# Return a char from different positions on a string

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, char

I am trying to build a query that will return different chars from different positions on a string. I'm using this query to get just the string i'll need from a bigger string:
    `MID(CStr(Movimento_Estoque_Cabecalho.Importados),1,(InStr(1,CStr(Movimento_Estoque_Cabecalho.Importados),"OD")-1))`

With that i'm getting a string that looks like this:
`OC0=35OC1=36`

I need to get only what's after the `=` positions.
In this case would be `35,36`

The Numbers returned after the `=` sign may vary from 1 to 999999.

Is that possible to do?

BTW, the database i'm using is MS-ACCESS 1997

Comment: If it is possible, can i get each value in a different row?

Comment: You don't need to comment to add to your own question.  Just edit the question.

Comment: Also, you show your entire input string?  I.e. what does `CStr(Movimento_Estoque_Cabecalho.Importados)` return?

Comment: I do not know vba very well but if you can use it in your access database I would first split the return result into a character array.  Second loop through character array and check if the characters are a number then you can place each character that is a number into another array or variable that will be your results.  You can place a conditional check in there somewhere to see if the number is after the  = sign.  I don't know if there is an easy way to do what you are trying to accomplish so I would start in this direction.

Comment: Since the column that is in use is a WIDEMEMO column, i use the CStr to convert the widememo info to a String...